# SOAP Call w/o WSDL body too large error

Tags: integration, webservices, soap, wsdl2apex, apex-variable

I am working on integrating an asmx webservice into salesforce. I was unable to parse the WSDL into apex, so have to build the calls manually. The call I built works and is received when literal string values are placed in the body. My problem is that when I substitute the literal values for variables that contain the same data, the server responds with a HTTP error 413, indicating that the body is too large. I'm not sure how to adjust since the call works when the variables are removed and values placed directly into the body. For example, this works:

```
xmlString += '<ACCOUNT_ID>1234</ACCOUNT_ID>';
xmlString += '<COMPANY_ID>1234</COMPANY_ID>';
xmlString += '<LAST_NAME>lname</LAST_NAME>';
xmlString += '<FIRST_NAME>fname</FIRST_NAME>';
xmlString += '<SSN>123456789</SSN>';
ect....
```

This one doesn't work, even though the values should all be the same:

```
 string accid='1234';
 string compid='1234';
 string lname='lname';
 ect.

 xmlString ='body headers here';
 xmlString += '<ACCOUNT_ID>'+accid+'</ACCOUNT_ID>';
 xmlString += '<COMPANY_ID>'+compid+'</COMPANY_ID>';
 xmlString += '<LAST_NAME>'+lname+'</LAST_NAME>';
 ect....
```

The server response it that the body is too large. Is there something I am missing or maybe a better way to manually build? Why does one way work and the other does not? Here is my HTTP call for reference. The XMLSTRING is the body sent:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint('https://myendpoint.asmx');
req.setheader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
req.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'https://mysoapaction.example');
req.setHeader('Host', 'myhost');
req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
req.setBody(xmlstring);
    system.debug('*****body*******'+xmlstring);
httpresponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('*****RESPONSE*******'+res);
```

Thanks in advance for any input. Not sure why one works and the other doesn't.

Here is an example of WSDL file I am trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="https://myaccount.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="https://myaccount.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://myaccount.com">
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/AccountsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/ClientsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/ClientsListWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/DebitsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PayeesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/DepositsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PayeesListWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PolicyGroupsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/DebitInfoWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/TransactionsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/BanksWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/BankAccountTypesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/BankHolidaysWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/NotesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentInfoWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/NsfStatusWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/StatesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/PreValidationsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/ClientsFailedValidationWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=ClientsFailedValidationWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/ClientsFailedValidationWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PaymentInfoWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentInfoWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PreValidationsWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PreValidationsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=BanksWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/BanksWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=StatesWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/StatesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=DepositsWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/DepositsWSDS.xsd"/>
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=NotesWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/NotesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=BankHolidaysWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/BankHolidaysWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=DebitsWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/DebitsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=BankAccountTypesWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/BankAccountTypesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=DebitInfoWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/DebitInfoWSDS.xsd"/>
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=TransactionsWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/TransactionsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PayeesWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PayeesWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=NsfStatusWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/NsfStatusWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PolicyGroupsWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PolicyGroupsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=AccountsWSDS" namespace="http://generic-api.myampaccount.com/WebServices/AccountsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PayeesListWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PayeesListWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=PaymentsWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/PaymentsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=ClientsListWSDS" namespace="http://tempuri.org/ClientsListWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:import schemaLocation="https://myaccount.com/webservices.asmx?schema=ClientsWSDS" namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/ClientsWSDS.xsd" />
      <s:element name="HelloWorld">
        <s:complexType />
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="AccountsGetA">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="accountID" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="activeFlag" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="inUse" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="pageSize" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="pageNumber" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="rowCount" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="pageCount" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="AccountsGetARes">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountsGetARes">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/AccountsWSDS.xsd" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="rowCount" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="pageCount" nillable="true" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ClientsSetA">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="clientsDataset">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any namespace="https://myaccount.com/WebServices/ClientsWSDS.xsd" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="DebitsSet">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="debitsDataSet">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any namespace="http://tempuri.org/DebitsWSDS.xsd" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="DebitsSetRes">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DebitsSetARes">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any namespace="http://tempuri.org/DebitsWSDS.xsd" />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="WSResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RecordID" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorDescription" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorld" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorldResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="AccountsGetASoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AccountsGetA" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="AccountsGetASoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AccountsGetARes" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ClientsSetASoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ClientsSetA" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ClientsSetASoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ClientsSetARes" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DebitsSetASoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DebitsSetA" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DebitsSetASoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DebitsSetARes" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebServicesSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:HelloWorldSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:HelloWorldSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AccountsGetA">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:AccountsGetASoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:AccountsGetASoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ClientsSetA">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ClientsSetASoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ClientsSetASoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DebitsSet">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DebitsSetSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DebitsSetSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebServicesSoap" type="tns:WebServicesSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://myaccount.com/HelloWorld" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AccountsGetA">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://myaccount.com/AccountsGetA" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ClientsSetA">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://myaccount.com/ClientsSetA" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="DebitsSetA">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://myaccount.com/DebitsSetA" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebServices">
    <wsdl:port name="WebServicesSoap" binding="tns:WebServicesSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://test.webservice.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="WebServicesSoap12" binding="tns:WebServicesSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://test.webservice.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: What is the `xmlString` length before and after using the variables? It seems likely that a value in one of the variables could be exceeding the length. The other possibility is that the XML with the variables is not well formed. E.g. What happens if one of the variables contains a `<` or `>` character.

Comment: Can you share your WSDL? There is likely an easier way of integrating with it. Feel free to change the endpoint URL.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I've updated to include a modified WSDL file that I was unable to import(changed the endpoint URL's and removed many of the references to inactive calls, but very close to the original). Any input is appreciated. I love your blog[link]( http://www.fishofprey.com/) you're articles have been a huge help with several projects. Thanks in advance for any input!!! I'll review the XmlString variable length as well as the character variable and let you know what I find.

Comment: Glad to hear the posts are helping. That WSDL isn't complete due to all the imports. Have you seen the alternative version of wsdl2apex I made? I might be able to help you here, http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html?